# how to change value maxitems of display menu links in Typo3?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

Hello I want to edit maxitems value to display links in typo3? I logged in from admin, click on 'Template', select main home page, and select combo box 'Template Aanlyzer', and click on lib.topmenu.

I can see there

```
    lib.firstlinks {
  10 = HMENU
  10.special = directory
  10.special.value = 82
  10.maxItems = 7
  10.entryLevel = 0
  10.1 = TMENU
  10.1 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
     NO.allWrap = <li><span>|</span></li>
     ACT = 1
     ACT.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
     ACT.allWrap = <li><span>|</span>|</li>
  }
}
```

so I want to change this 10.maxItems = 7 value, but not able to edit it, so how can i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Template analyzer` only displays code (sumarized in whole root path).

Use `Info/modify`, find proper TypoScript template and search this declaration in `Setup` field

Comment: `10.maxItems = 8` ;> or remove it, when it will display all items